# Apex Code Version Control

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

Is there any way to integrate version control system for Apex & Visualforce code? I can thinking of keeping a separate repository but no way to have it integrated with Salesforce Platform.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for reminding! I just accepted it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by using Subversion and the Force.com Eclipse IDE with the Subclipse plugin.

Here are a few links to some instructions.

- [Setting up Subversion (Windows)](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/setting-up-subversion-on-windows.html)
- [Installing Force.com IDE (Eclipse)](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation)
- [Installing Subclipse (Eclipse plugin)](http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA)

  - Use the update site when installing in Eclipse - [similar to the instructions here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation_for_Eclipse_3.6)

Comment: This is the approach we took also, it's not integrated with the platform itself, but it does mean we have a back and full history available to us when we need it.

Comment: Thanks Matthew! I will try using that approach.

Comment: Recently, there have been [issues](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/Eclipse-Force-com-IDE-Plugin-Install-Error/td-p/242577) installing the IDE to the "Program Files" folder on Windows. If you run into an error, install the IDE to C:\ instead.

Answer (score 6):

If instead of using Subversion, you wish to use Git (lots of the community code is hosted on GitHub where you can get it for free) then have a look at [this Dreamforce session](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4C2Jy-74sU) and some hints and tips about how best to use Git and Force.com together [here](http://paulbattisson.com/?p=112).